# Alternatives to show that $|\mathbb{R}|>|\mathbb{Z}|$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Cantor's Diagonal Argument is the standard proof of this theorem. However there must be other proofs, what are some of these proofs?

I am asking this because whenever I think of this question, I immediately think of the Cantor's Argument, which kills the possibility of  other interesting finds.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks, I still can't do that sort of thing ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

picakhu: This was [posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46970/proofs-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals/) on MO and there were some interesting answers. I believe the answer I gave there avoids any hidden use of diagonalization. Other answers there are interesting and useful to think about even if, at the end, a diagonal argument is lurking.

Below is an abridged version of my answer there. It assumes some knowledge of ordinals.

---

In a more general fashion, the question can be restated as:

> Is there a proof of Cantor's theorem that ${}|X|<|{\mathcal P}(X)|$ that is not a diagonal argument?

I learned the following in A. Kanamori-D. Pincus. "Does GCH imply AC locally?", in **Paul Erdős and his mathematics, II (Budapest, 1999)**, 413-426, Bolyai Soc. Math. Stud., 11, János Bolyai Math. Soc., Budapest, 2002. It dates back to Zermelo's 1904 well-ordering paper.

**a.** It is enough to show that there is no injection $F:{\mathcal P}(Y)\to Y$ for any set $Y$.

**b.** If there is such an injection $F$ we can (definably from $F$) produce a pair $(A,B)$ with $A\ne B$ and $F(A)=F(B)$. In effect, Zermelo proved that:

> For any $F:{\mathcal P}(Y)\to Y$ there is a unique  a unique well-ordering $(W, \lt)$ with $W\subseteq Y$ such that:
>
> 1. $\forall x\in W (F (\{y ∈ W \mid y \lt x\}) = x)$, and
> 2. $F (W )\in W$.

We can then take $A=W$ and $B=\{y\in W\mid y\lt F(W)\}$.

**c.** *Zermelo's theorem* can be proved using the (set theoretic) recursion theorem and *Hartogs theorem* that for any set $A$ there is a least ordinal $\alpha$ does not inject into $A$. Neither uses diagonalization.

Comment: This goes above my head! Though it seems to be true based on the other users up's, I just wish I could understand it.

Comment: How can one claim that no "hidden use of diagonalization" is employed without any precise formal definition of such?  At first glance it seems to me that there could well be a hidden use of diagonalization above.

Comment: @Bill: I agree, there was a behind the scenes debate at MO about this question. It would be nice (perhaps even useful in other contexts) to have a formal definition rather than a social understanding here.  All I can say is I have checked the details to the best resolution my <del>microscope<\del>patience allows, and I didn't seen any.

Answer (score 2):

Cantor's diagonal argument shows that a given function cannot be surjective.

One can construct the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and thus show $|P(\mathbb{N})| \le |\mathbb{R}|$ and from [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) it follows that $|\mathbb{N}| < |P(\mathbb{N})|$.

(of course, I've been using the fact $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}|$ freely here)

Edit:
Do note that this way doesn't really use any implicit diagonalization argument. It just uses the two facts that $|\mathbb{N}|<|P(\mathbb{N})|$ and that $|P(\mathbb{N})|\le|\mathbb{R}|$. There's something to be said about the fact that the "natural" injection of $P(\mathbb{N})$ into the Cantor set only works for the infinite subsets and not for most finite subsets, however from Cantor's theorem we have that the "most" of the power set is the infinite subsets anyway, and thus this is not a real problem.

Comment: This doesn't work.  You need |P(N)| = |R|.  And once you have it, in what sense does this avoid diagonalization?

Comment: No, you need $|\mathbb{N}|<|P(\mathbb{N})|\le|\mathbb{R}|$, which is what I described above. I don't think that the Cantor set construction can be seen as a proper diagonalization, although one could argue that it does in fact hide down there - beneath its irrational core.

Comment: Asaf: I guess the key point of Qiaochu's remark is that the usual proofs of Cantor's theorem are diagonal arguments.

Comment: Andres: I know the proof which uses Russell's paradox in a "valid" way. Doesn't look much like diagonalization to me, but like I said - one can argue that it is hidden down there somehow. While I'm at it, I'd like to remark that this proof is exceptionally short and elegant and no doubt the best proof I've seen in my B.Sc. and a year ago I wrote it on a small piece of paper for the bartender in my usual pub.

Comment: "Russell's paradox" *is* diagonalization. I agree this argument is short and elegant.

Comment: PS. What did the bartender say?

Comment: @Andres, this is much like someone once told me "Have you seen any proof that was not an inductive proof recently??". He was joking, of course, but he wasn't that far from the truth. Most of the proofs are somewhat inductive (at least from the point of view we were talking about - undergrad related theorems, and in particular freshmen theorems from the introductory course in logic and set theory).

Comment: @Andres: He said thanks. Free booze is a regular thing for me in that pub, so I can't say I got any special treatment. Later on he did agree with me that the proof is very elegant and memorable. I don't think they had it in their exam. If I would be writing the course exam - I'd have given this theorem as a question, instead of the Cantor-Bernstein one they like to use. I recommended it, but not sure if it's gonna go through.

Comment: @Asaf : :-) Hehe.

Comment: @Asaf: sorry, ignore the first part of my comment.  But I still think you need to provide a proof of Cantor's theorem without diagonalization, which is the point of the question.

Comment: @Qiaochu: To be nitpicky and mathematician about your comment and the original question, there was a requirement to avoid the Cantor diagonalization argument, not any diagonalization argument. The fact that one is hidden underneath the surface is fine, as long as it's not Cantor's original diagonalization argument.

Comment: @Asaf: I assumed "Cantor's diagonalization argument" _was_ this argument.  What is "Cantor's argument" if it isn't this one?  (My impression is that most people who learn "Cantor's diagonalization argument" don't learn Cantor's original proof.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: Cantor's diagonalization argument is that given a function from the natural numbers to the real numbers you can produce a number which is not in the range of the function.

Comment: @Asaf: that argument is essentially equivalent to the usual proof of Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Of course, Cantor's theorem is a generalization of this argument. However it is not the original one.

Answer (score 2):

I read about this proof in Raymond Smullyan's book "Satan, Cantor and Infinity". The proof is due to Willaim Zwicker (according to the book) and involves something called a hypergame. I'll first mentioned the hypergame paradox (because it's fun and can give an insight about the proof) and then write the proof.

Let's call a game with turns a *normal* game if it always ends in finite turns. For example tic-tac-toe and checkers are both normal games. Now imagine the following game which I will call *hypergame*: In the first turn the first player names a normal game. In the second turn the second player plays the first move of the normal game named and then the players continue playing that game in turns.

The paradox arises from the question: Is the hypergame a normal game? Assume that it is and assume that we try to play hypergame: I go first and say "Let's play hypergame" (I can do that since it's a normal game). Then it's your turn and you can say "Let's play hypergame" and so forth. Thus the hypergame cannot be normal since if it is we can start a hypergame that doesn't end in finite turns. But if the hypergame isn't normal then every hypergame will end in finite turns (since every game I will name will end in finite moves and our game will last that number of turns plus one) which will make the hypergame normal!

Now the proof: Assume that a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and let's assume that $f$ sends $n$ to $X_n$. We define a *path* of numbers as a finite or infinite sequence of numbers such that an element $n$ of the path is either the last (and the path is finite) or the successor of $n$ belongs in $X_n$. For example take a number $n$. If $m\in X_n$ then a successor of $n$ in a path can be $m$. If $X_n$ is empty then $n$ is always the last element of a path. Now we call an element  $n\in\mathbb{N}$ *normal* if every path that begins with $n$ is finite.

Finally take the set $Z$ that contains exactly all the normal elements of $\mathbb{N}$. It's easy to see that there doesn't exist an $n_0$ such that $Z=X_{n_0}$, which would mean that $f$ is not onto. The argument is essentially the same as the one I used above: Assume that $Z=X_{n_0}$. If $n_0\in Z$ then there is an infinite path, namely $(n_0,n_0,n_0,\ldots)$, but $Z$ is the set of all normal elements so that's impossible. If $n\notin Z$ then there is an infinite path that begins with $n_0$ (by the definition of $Z$). Let's call it $(n_0,m,k,\ldots)$. But then there is an infinite path that begins with $m$ (take the aforementioned path and remove $n_0$ from the start). This is again impossible since $m\in Z$ (by the definition of a path) and every element of $Z$ is normal.

This proof uses self-reference but doesn't seem to use the diagonal lemma. I don't know if it's hidden somewhere in the proof (though it looks to me like it isn't).

Comment: Honestly, it seems like an ad-hoc proof that for every set $X$ we have $|X|<|P(X)|$.

Comment: Asaf, what do you mean when you say "ad hoc proof" exactly?

Comment: I mean that this proof is really a proof for Cantor's theorem, but without mentioning that - and only for the case we take the set as the natural numbers.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, actually even in the book Smullyan presents it in the more general way. For some reason I decided to write it overly specific and then forgot to mention that it generalises. So thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sure :-) Just for future reference, if you're replying to someone who is not the writer of the answer/question your commenting to, do use his username as it alerts him to the fact he got a reply.

Answer (score 2):

Cantor had several other proofs before coming up with the diagonalization argument.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof for one version.  Or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23953/earliest-diagonal-proof-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals.)
I also read a recent account of this in a Math Monthly article. (I think a version of that article is at http://www.math.jhu.edu/~wright/Cantor_Pick_Phi.pdf.)

The "Nested Intervals" proof is really very nice.  Assume the reals are countable and so arrange them as a sequence.  Then use that ordering to create intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ where $a_{n-1}<a_n<b_n <b_{n-1}$.  The intersection of this sequence of nested intervals is nonempty (this is the Nested Intervals theorem) yet no real number in our list can be inside it!  This contradiction proves that we could not have originally arranged the reals in a sequence.

Comment: The nested intervals is the proof I was shown when taking the introductory course to set theory. However when you think about it, this is really a diagonalization argument.

Comment: Hmmm -- I'm not sure what you mean.  The "nested intervals" proof is similarly a proof by contradiction, constructing a "missing" real....  Is that what you mean?  Or am I missing something more?

Comment: The one I saw was creating a sequence of nested closed intervals, and by the Cantor's lemma the intersection of them all was non-empty, and it had a number which was not in the range of the function.